# Set default shipping method if multiple shipping methods are available - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to set default shipping method if multiple shipping methods are available in checkout page.

Answer (score 3):

Override the Magento 2 file Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js

Add this condition in resolveShippingRates method.

```
if (ratesData.length >= 1) {
//set shipping rate if we have only one available shipping rate
    if(!selectedShippingRate) {
        selectShippingMethodAction(ratesData[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working fine, and it does select one of the shipping method as default. but how to get orer total updated when using onestepcheckout? right now the update total is updated only when clicking on the shipping method.